# Get fact that satisfied OR condition in LHS

Tags: clips

How can I get the fact that satisfied an or condition in a LHS?

E.g. I tried but failed with this:

```
(defrule rule
    ?f<-(or (fact1) (fact2))
    =>
    (retract ?f)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only bind a pattern conditional element to a pattern address. Just distribute the pattern address bindings to the specific pattern you want bound in each disjunct of the or conditional element. For example:

```
(defrule rule
  (or ?f <- (fact1) 
      ?f <- (fact2)
      (and (fact3)
           ?f <- (fact4)))
  =>
  (retract ?f))
```